# CSS Drop Down issue

Tags: html, css

I have a very big issue with the Drop Down menu i have used the Css and HTML for the same.

The problem what i am facing is i need the background width of the nav to be 100% to the ontainer but niw when i am increasing  the horizontal menu its shifting to next line

can you please help

```
body{

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 87.5%;

}

.container{

  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  border:10px solid #0171bd;
}

.nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.nav ul {
  background: #efefef; 
  background: linear-gradient(top, #0077bb 0%, #0171bd 100%);  
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0077bb 0%, #0171bd 100%); 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0077bb 0%,#0171bd 100%); 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;  
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;

}
.nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

.nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
.nav ul li:hover {
    background: #bee6ff;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #bee6ff 0%, #7dcdff 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bee6ff 0%, #ffffff 50%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bee6ff 0%,#7dcdff 40%);
  }
.nav ul li:hover a {
      color: #363636;

    }

.nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 20px 12px;
    color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;
  }

  .nav ul ul {
  background: #bee6ff;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #bee6ff 0%, #7dcdff 40%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bee6ff 0%, #ffffff 50%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bee6ff 0%,#7dcdff 40%);

  border-radius: 0px; 
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
  .nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6cbdef;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6cbdef;
    position: relative;
  }
    .nav ul ul li a {
      padding: 15px 10px;
      color: #fff;

    } 
      .nav ul ul li a:hover {
        background: #0075bb;
        color:#FFF;
      }
      .nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

HTML Code is like below

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">Site Settings</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="meta-tags.php">Add Meta Tags</a></li>
                        <li><a href="page-title.php">Add Page Title</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">User Managment</a></li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">Upload Images</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Upload Slider Image</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Upload Ads Image</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Content Managment</a></li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">Devotees</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Add Devotee</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Edit Devotee</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">News</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Add News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Edit News</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">Donation</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">View Request</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Approve Request</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">Blogs</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Add Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Edit Blog</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: are you looking for this http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/xbyPYm ?

Comment: No every thing is working fine here... but what i need is the background of the primary UL to be 100%

Comment: I mean it's your code, I've done few changes to it, So this how your code should behave or not?

Comment: i mean when you remove the Main Devotee automatical the background is going to reduce... when you add the item its going to increase, i need the back ground to be fixed

Comment: The original code is exactly the same there is no change in that... i just need to fix the width of background main UL so it will not reduce and increase

Comment: .nav ul {width: 200px;} will do the same thing

Comment: yeah when i do that all the sub menu UL are also increasing.. that is what is the problem

Comment: .nav ul ul {width: auto;} try it!

Comment: sounds good, you are welcome :)
I've added the answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is answer for [same](http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/xbyPYm)

```
.nav ul ul {
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check once

```css
body{

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 87.5%;

}

.container{

  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  border:10px solid #0171bd;
}

.nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.nav ul {
  background: #efefef; 
  background: linear-gradient(top, #0077bb 0%, #0171bd 100%);  
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0077bb 0%, #0171bd 100%); 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0077bb 0%,#0171bd 100%); 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;  
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;

}
#nav > ul{display: table;}
.nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

.nav > ul > li {
  display: table-cell;
}
.nav ul li:hover {
    background: #bee6ff;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #bee6ff 0%, #7dcdff 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bee6ff 0%, #ffffff 50%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bee6ff 0%,#7dcdff 40%);
  }
.nav ul li:hover a {
      color: #363636;

    }

.nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 20px 12px;
    color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;
  }

  .nav ul ul {
  background: #bee6ff;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #bee6ff 0%, #7dcdff 40%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bee6ff 0%, #ffffff 50%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bee6ff 0%,#7dcdff 40%);

  border-radius: 0px; 
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
  .nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6cbdef;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6cbdef;
    position: relative;
  }
    .nav ul ul li a {
      padding: 15px 10px;
      color: #fff;

    } 
      .nav ul ul li a:hover {
        background: #0075bb;
        color:#FFF;
      }
      .nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 992px) {
/* Styles */
    .nav ul{
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 0 5px;
    }
     .nav > ul > li > a{
         padding: 10px 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">Site Settings</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="meta-tags.php">Add Meta Tags</a></li>
                        <li><a href="page-title.php">Add Page Title</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">User Managment</a></li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">Upload Images</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Upload Slider Image</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Upload Ads Image</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Content Managment</a></li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">Devotees</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Add Devotee</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Edit Devotee</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">News</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Add News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Edit News</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">Donation</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">View Request</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Approve Request</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">Blogs</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Add Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Edit Blog</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

you can decrease font-size for lower version using media queries.